# How to Merge two ArrayAdapter in One and Show it in one listview

Tags: android

I have two custom adapter and I want to merge it in one Adapter
Adapter carrying name and mac information
I had seen lots of question but didnt understand clearly what to do
THANKS BEFORE

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataPro> {

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<DataPro> collect) {
    super(context, resource, collect);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
    DataPro item = getItem(position);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setText(item.Name+" : "+item.Mac);
    return textView;
}
}
```

MyAdapter2.java

```
public class MyAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<Datapro2> {
public MyAdapter2(Context context, int resource, List<Datapro2> collect1) {
    super(context, resource, collect1);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
    Datapro2 item = getItem(position);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setText(item.Name);
    return textView;
}
}
```

In this Below java class i am showing data in two different listview i want to show it in one

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listOfDatabaseObject;
ListView listView;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
List<DataPro> result;
List<Datapro2> results;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    listOfDatabaseObject = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase =userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    result = userDbHelper.getItemFromDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, result);
    listOfDatabaseObject.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    results = userDbHelper.getItemFromDatabase2(sqLiteDatabase);
    MyAdapter2 adapter2 = new MyAdapter2(getApplicationContext(), 0, results);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

DataPro.java

```
public class DataPro {
String Name;
String Mac;

public DataPro(String Name, String Mac)
{
    this.Name=Name;
    this.Mac=Mac;
}
}
```

Datapro2.java

```
public class Datapro2 {
String Name;

public Datapro2(String Name)
{
    this.Name=Name;
}
}
```

DataBaseclass.java

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DB_NAME = "STUDENTINFO.DB";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
String query = "SELECT * FROM " +MainActivity.collect+ " where " +Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC+ " in(select "+Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC+ " FROM " +MainActivity.collect2+");";
String query2 =  "SELECT " + Coloumn.NewInfo.NAME + " FROM " +MainActivity.collect+ " where " +Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC+ " not in(select "+Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC+ " FROM " +MainActivity.collect2+");";

 public UserDbHelper(Context context)
 {
     super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
 }
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
}
public void AddInformation(String name,String mac,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Coloumn.NewInfo.NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC,mac);
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(MainActivity.collect,null,contentValues);
}
public void AddInformation2(String name,String mac,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Coloumn.NewInfo.NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(Coloumn.NewInfo.MAC,mac);
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(MainActivity.collect2,null,contentValues);
}
public List<DataPro> getItemFromDatabase(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    List<DataPro> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        result.add(
                new DataPro(
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mac"))
                )
        );
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}

public List<Datapro2> getItemFromDatabase2(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    List<Datapro2> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query2,null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        result.add(
                new Datapro2(
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"))

                )
        );
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}




@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only 1 Adapter, and can use any tag(integer) to manage them differently.

For Ex. :

Take an extra int in DataProWrapper class.

```
public class{
   public DataPro dataProObject;
   public int type;
}
```

Ex. `public int type = 0;` (set 0 for first adapter, set 1 for 2nd adapter)

*set in objects (DataProWrapper list), you are sending in Adapter's constructor.*

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataPro> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<DataProWrapper> collect) {
        super(context, resource, collect);
        // save to use in getView() method
        this.collect = collect;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // get type value
        DataPro object = collect.get(position).dataProObject;
        if(object.type == 0){
             // first adapter
             TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
             DataPro item = getItem(position);
             textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
             textView.setText(item.Name+" : "+item.Mac);
             return textView;
        }else{
             //Second adapter
             TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
             Datapro2 item = getItem(position);
             textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
             textView.setText(item.Name);
             return textView;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: if i am using one apdater i am getting error while retriving data..like i am retreving only name..getting error like remove second parameter from datapro

Comment: you can use another class to add that type integer.like i have edited in my code

Comment: get value with         DataPro object = collect.get(position).dataProObject;

Comment: instead of take type in DataPro, use DataProWrapper

Comment: i want to show both table data at same time in one listview